# Einstein Email Recommendation Content Creation

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, einstein, einstein-recommendations

We want to build a single block of code to be used across a number of Email activities, and we want to "force" one of the variables.  Let's assume that we are selling recipes and I want to trigger an email to people who told us on sign-up that they want Banana recipes, or Apple or Pear or whatever.

In many recommendation tools I can usually add a parameter to the URL to "force" part of the recommendation, but this doesn't seem to be the case with Einstein.

Here's a sample URL:  `https://XXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5cdc80b8f....55914e6801/l/1/%%emailaddr%%`

is there something along the line of adding the "fruit" parameter so the URL might be:
   `https://XXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5cdc80b8f...55914e6801/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?fruit=banana`

Even better would be a personalized value for fruit, so it becomes: `https://XXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5cdc80b8ff8b6155914e6801/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?fruit=%%fruit%%`

Possible? How can we manage this type of ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this page [Customize the Calls](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_customize_the_calls.htm&type=5) and also the page [Rule Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_personalization_rule_manager.htm&type=5)

The call should be similar to:

`https://XXXX.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5cdc80b8ff8b6155914e6801/l/1/%%emailaddr%%?ITEM=%%fruit%%`

And then in Rule manager create a rule to `Emphasize/Include items when FRUIT/Category is same as reference item`

Comment: I should add -- using the answer above, the value for "%%Fruit%%" must match the catalog item's unique identifier.  So if "banana" is marked as "BNA" as the key in the catalog then we need to insert BNA into the API/XML call for "item="